# Why Electron+React has different act in Dev and Prod Mode?

Tags: reactjs, electron

i have a REACT Component inside of my [electron app](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate). (Main) and
i want use "[electron-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log)" from my component (Renderer).

when i use below code inside of my Renderer on **DEV Mode, it works**!
but when i *build* app, i get white-screen-of-death without any error!

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const elog = remote.require('electron-log');
```

why?